# Checkboxes not working with Javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dialog, tiles

I'm turning several jsp pages on dialogs using Tiles framework.

The problem is that several jsp have checkboxes and those checkboxes seems no work on dialog.

This is a sample of how my checkboxes work: 
Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function setValueCheckbox(identifier) {
        if (identifier == "typeDpr") {
            if ($('input[name=typeDpr]').is(':checked')) {
                $("#typeDpr").val("DPR");
            } else {
                $("#typeDpr").val(null);
            }
        }   
    }

</script>

<c:set var="dpr" value="DPR" />
 <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${requestScope.view.from eq insert}">
        <c:set value="${param.typeDpr}" var="varTypeDpr" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set value="${requestScope.view.typeDpr}" var="varTypeDpr" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And the checkbox:

```
 <td>
   <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${varTypeDpr eq dpr}">
      <input type="checkbox" id="typeDpr" name="typeDpr" value="${varTypeDpr}" onclick="javascript: setValueCheckbox(this.id);" checked="checked" />
   </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
      <input type="checkbox" id="typeDpr" name="typeDpr" value="${varTypeDpr}" onclick="javascript: setValueCheckbox(this.id);" />
  </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
     <fmt:message key="investigation.events.section.typeDpr" bundle="${i}" />
</td>
```

If not selected, my checkbox should be set to NULL, instead the checkbox should be populated with a String ("DRP" on this case).

The problem:

If I don't change the checkboxes, they all work perfectly but if I try click on a checkbox, they are always evaluated as null.

Comment: Try $(element).prop('checked') instead of $(element).is(':checked')

Comment: It doesen't work.